# ListView filter only works on first item

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a filter that searches through a list view containing an arraylist of Labels (usernames):

```
public void updateList() {
    UserDAO theDAO = new UserDAO();
    userList = theDAO.storeUsers();
    listView.setItems(userList);
    filterField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldVal, Object newVal) {
            search((String) oldVal, (String) newVal);
        }
    });
}

public void search(String oldVal, String newVal) {
    if (oldVal != null && (newVal.length() < oldVal.length())) {
        listView.setItems(userList);
    }
    String value = newVal.toUpperCase();
    ObservableList<Label> secondList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (Object entry : listView.getItems()) {
        boolean match = true;
        Label entryText = (Label) entry;

        if (!entryText.getText().toUpperCase().contains(value)) {
            match = false;
            break;
        }

        if (match) {
            secondList.add(entryText);
        }
    }
    listView.setItems(secondList);
}
```

As of now, my ListView contains:

test
123
third

Whenever I type any letter in "test", it succesfully filters out "third" and "123" and only displays "test" in the ListView; shouldn't it also display "third" when I type "t"?

Also, when I type "123" or "third" into the filter it filters out everything.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer while digging through the internet - I just removed the break statement to allow it to keep searching.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use a `FilteredList` instead of doing the filtering on your own.
Furthermore in most cases you should avoid using `Node`s in as item type of the `ListView` (`String`s usually should do the trick too...).
Finally use type parameters instead of casting the items from `Object` to `Label` (or some other class). This allows the compiler to do some type checks and also usually leads to shorter code:

```
ObservableList<String> originalList = ...
FilteredList<String> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(originalList);

ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(filteredList);

TextField filterField = new TextField();
filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->  {
    if (newValue.isEmpty()) {
        filteredList.setPredicate(null);
    } else {
        final String searchString = newValue.toUpperCase();
        filteredList.setPredicate(s -> s.toUpperCase().contains(searchString));
    }
});
```